# facebook sharing in ios 9 using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have facebook sharing concept in my app. I need to share the image url, description and when the user click on the image in FB, this will goto website. i used many methods like SLComposeViewController, FBSDKShareLinkContent, FBShareDialogParams.Sometimes these are all working fine. sometimes not working. Now FBShareDialogParams is deprecated in ios 9. Which code is working fine in ios9. Is any one know???

Comment: And also, i getting com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated, this warning while using SLComposerViewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code:-

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *sharecontent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
sharecontent.contentTitle = @"Hello ... My Dear Friends";
sharecontent.contentDescription =@"share this images";
sharecontent.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.picgifs.com/glitter-gifs/c/congratulations/picgifs-congratulations-178787.gif"];
sharecontent.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com"];

FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.fromViewController = self;
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.shareContent = sharecontent;
[dialog show];
```

// PRAGMA :- Delegate Method

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"Finished");
}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's right and working fine. but it take only the contentURL to share on the fb. the image url(image) and the title isn't showing any where in the post.

Comment: FBShareDialogParams is deprecated in ios9. instead of this, what i should use for this fb share.